# how to use react router usePrompt for switching the tab in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, prompt

I am creating a react router prompt, so here I want to apply the prompt when you want to switch from one tab to another. I have applied the prompt property, but it's not working. Have any suggestions for that? How do I make that prompt so that when I want to switch from one tab to another in every route, it shows the message.

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  useHistory,
  usePrompt,
  useBlocker,
  Navigate
} from "react-router-dom";
import Demo from "./Demo";
import About from "./About";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
export default function App() {
  const [login, setLogin] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Demo />
      <button onClick={() => setLogin(!login)}>
        {login ? "LogOut" : "LogIn"}
      </button>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} onLeave={ BlockingForm } />
        {/*Pass Props to a Component Rendered by React Router */}
        <Route path="/about" element={<About login={login} />} onLeave={ BlockingForm }/>
        {/* if you want to navigate home page if no page found  */}
        <Route
          path="*"
          element={true ? <NotFound /> : <Navigate replace to="/" />}
        />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
function Home() {
  return <div>Home component</div>;
}

function NotFound() {
  return <div>404 Not Found Page</div>;
}
function BlockingForm() {
  let [isBlocking, setIsBlocking] = useState(false);

  usePrompt(
    "Hello from usePrompt -- Are you sure you want to leave?",
    isBlocking
  );
  // useBlocker(
  //   () => "Hello from useBlocker -- are you sure you want to leave?",
  //   isBlocking
  // );

  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={(event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.target.reset();
        setIsBlocking(false);
      }}
    >
      <p>
        Blocking? {isBlocking ? "Yes, click a link or the back button" : "Nope"}
      </p>

      <p>
        <input
          size="50"
          placeholder="type something to block transitions"
          onChange={(event) => {
            setIsBlocking(event.target.value.length > 0);
          }}
        />
      </p>

      <p>
        <button>Submit to stop blocking</button>
      </p>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: IIRC the prompt would only be validly used if the user is about to leave the browsing context, i.e. close the current window/tab, or reloading the page, etc. Switching to another browsing context only backgrounds the current window/tab.

Comment: How do I apply prompt over that code also?

Comment: Maybe implement something with the [page visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API).